# How to inject Webpack bundle's file name into DefinePlugin `process.env` in Webpack config

Tags: webpack

I am making two bundles one is for service worker and one is the application code using webpack and I want to inject the file name of service-worker.js file which contains a hash in the file name into the process.env variable so I can use the file name to load it using ajax in my code. Is there a way to pass the file name with the hash into the application code using one webpack config and one build process.